# My Thinkpad W530 gets an error message that pops up several times a day

Tags: thinkpad

It's a black box that says "resolution notice" on the top.  It asks me to change my resolution several times a day.  How do I get rid of this message?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: @Fazer87 Windows 7

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of this message for us?

Comment: What resolution are you at? What resolution s are available in the display preferences?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Intel Driver:
Find the Intel Graphics Media driver in the System Tray. Right Click on it --> Graphics options --> Balloon Notification --> Optimal Resolution Notification --> Disable

There are similar options for the range of NVIDIA Driver available for this laptop (Quadro and Optimus drivers), but as I dont have them available to me, I cant give a step by step.

Also, check if you are allowing windows to decide if your resolution is optimal:
System Properties> Performance> Advanced> Visual Effects: choose the "customize" option. The "customize" and "performance" settings should bypass any automatic adjustments that Windows would want to initiate.